# How to change gem package manager's version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, package-managers

Currently I am having gem package manager version 2.0.14, I found it by running

```
gem -v
```

but how to downgrade the package manager to version 1.8.25. Every search attempt to find this leads me to, how to upgrading or downgrading a particular gem.

Answer (score 1):

Gem can be updated using:

```
gem update --system
```

or

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you are referring to rvm?

```
rvm list
rvm use 2.0.0-p353 // just a sample version
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
sudo gem update --system 1.8.25  # If you don't mention version then by default it will update with latest one
```

More information about downgrading/upgrading rubygems: http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/UPGRADING_rdoc.html