# How to change the GEM package manager version, not particular gem/module/package

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Yes I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432595/how-to-change-gem-package-managers-version) question but, no answer was given. So is there such option?
In order to provide more information in the body I will repeat the title: How to change the version of GEM? Not gem as module or a package, the program gem that is installed along with ruby.

Comment: explain more what you want? you need have different gemlist and can use different gemlist?

Comment: or downgrading from 3.x.x to 2.x.x?